# Make server get all internet requirement before sending web page

Tags: html, apache, webserver

I'm currently working on a local website to display weather.

I did find a nice way to show a widget using an app from http://www.meteocity.com/widget/ but it's not really working on some of our local computer because some don't have internet, just access to the server.

Here is an example of code from the widget :

```
<div id="cont_NzUwNTZ8NXwxfDF8MXxGRkZGRkZ8MXxGRkZGRkZ8Y3wx"><div id="spa_NzUwNTZ8NXwxfDF8MXxGRkZGRkZ8MXxGRkZGRkZ8Y3wx"><a id="a_NzUwNTZ8NXwxfDF8MXxGRkZGRkZ8MXxGRkZGRkZ8Y3wx" href="http://www.meteocity.com/france/paris_v75056/" target="_blank" style="color:#333;text-decoration:none;">Météo Paris</a> ©<a href="http://www.meteocity.com">meteocity.com</a></div><script type="text/javascript" src="http://widget.meteocity.com/js/NzUwNTZ8NXwxfDF8MXxGRkZGRkZ8MXxGRkZGRkZ8Y3wx"></script></div>
```

I would like my server to get the internet info and show the widget without any internet requirement, but I don't really know how to do that.

Can I mirror the html on my server ?
Can I add parameters so that the server get the info before it shows it ?

Any help would be greatly appreciated ? (Don't hesitate to ask me if my question is not clear).

Comment: Ok so I think I have found a workaround.

I'm currently hosting the widget in a page on my server and when I need it I call it using the web page link. I'll update if it works.

Comment: Didn't work. I've even tried php file_get_content and curl but the server forbid me to use it to get data from the page. I suppose there is no workaround :/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sadly it didn't work.
I wasn't allowed to get the value because the server provider didn't allow non-human user to get it.

I used a plugin to have something similar but on the server side.